# How to simplify schema in Json.NET Schema

Tags: c#, json, schema

Simply, I have a class of such a structure:

```
public class Example
{
    [JsonProperty("field-1", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public Node f1;

    [JsonProperty("field-2", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public Node f2;

    [JsonProperty("field-3", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public Node f3;
}
```

There are numerous fields of that kind. Is it possible to simplify this? I use this for the purpose of schema generating.